# Google V8 source - percentage char (%) before function javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

Looking at some files from Google V8 js source code I found for example this JS file:

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js

There are many functions preceded from a precentage `%` char

ex.  `%CheckIsBootstrapping();`

Is that valid JS (the file is `array.js`) ? (what kind?)

What does that mean?

Thx